# Order of subgroup generated by $ \{ 2,...,k \}$ in multiplicative group $(\mathbb{Z}/ N\mathbb{Z})^\times$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, multiplicative-order

Suppose $ \{ 2,3,4,...,k \}$ is such that no element in it is a factor of N. Then is there a way of determining how large $k$ has to be, in order to generate at least half of $(\mathbb{Z}/ \text{N}\mathbb{Z})^\times$?

For smaller N, having just $\{ 2 \}$ works fine, however I'm not sure how this extends to larger N.

N can be assumed either prime or composite, and is not Carmichael.

Comment: The first $N$ such that $\{2\}$ does not sufifce are $31,43,51,63,65$.

Comment: I think you need to suppose that no element in $ \{ 2,...,k \}$ has a factor in common with $N$.

Comment: Please share any data you have.

Comment: Thanks, I'll write a program to try and get some more data. This is related to choosing bases for the Fermat prime test. N is assumed non-Carmichael, and  either prime or composite, whichever is easier to work with.

Comment: Yes, none of the elements in the set have a common factor with N. Also the set is the first k natural numbers. I have since edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: The first $N$ such that $\{2,3\}$ does not suffice are $247,259,307,431,439,485,499$.